# I can't get a statu from XHR ajax call

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get a response back from at REST API using type script.

I did the most simple implementation I could come up with, but I get no response.

I would expect to get an error code, but I get nothing.

The script is running inside of EXCEL Script Lab.

Here is the code.

Typescript:

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let raw = JSON.stringify({ dsvAccount: "6402105440" });

    xhr.open("POST", "https://api.dsv.com/xp/booking/v1/bookings");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.onload = function () {
      console.log(xhr.statustext);
    };
    xhr.send(raw);
   });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="run" class="ms-Button">
    <span class="ms-Button-label">Run</span>
</button>
```

BR Kresten

Comment: Could this be a cross-origin issue?

Comment: Could be...I tried to use https://js.do/ and from there i got a cross-origin error. I have tried to use a simple VBA and Python script, and I have no problem getting a response. How can I overcome a cross-origin issue in typescript?

Comment: I found an explanation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations

Comment: Jay, you can post an answer? That was a very good hint, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a cross-orgin issue because Office add-ins are hosted in a browser control.  As Kresten mentioned, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations for a work around.